# Where should `setxkbmap us_programmer` go to make it persistent?

Tags: .profile, xkb

Where should my custom `setxkbmap us_programmer` goto to make it persistent when I log into Ubuntu graphically and also from SSH?

Comment: Have you tried to add it to your input sources in **Settings -> Keyboard** ?

Comment: is apprantly does not show up...
i used https://github.com/eren/programmer-qwerty/blob/master/linux/us_programmer

Comment: Well, apparently not if you didn't edit evdev.xml accordingly. But you may want to try to add the setxkbmap command to your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: OTOH it's not clear to me what it is you want to achieve. If you enable the file that way, only the first "basic" section is used. The rest of the file is unnecessary noise. I'd say that the GitHub page you linked to does not apply to a desktop with a modern graphical interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would want to use that layout, this is how I would probably do it.

First add this variant to the bottom of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "programmer" {

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1] = "English (US, programmer)";

    key <AE01> {    [      exclam,  1   ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [          at,  2   ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [  numbersign,  3   ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [      dollar,  4   ]   };
    key <AE05> {    [     percent,  5   ]   };
    key <AE06> {    [ asciicircum,  6   ]   };
    key <AE07> {    [   ampersand,  7   ]   };
    key <AE08> {    [    asterisk,  8   ]   };
    key <AE09> {    [   parenleft,  9   ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [  parenright,  0   ]   };
};
```

Then add this entry to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` within the `<variantList></variantList>` of the `us` layout:

```
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>programmer</name>
            <description>English (US, programmer)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
```

After next login I can then add the layout in *Settings -> Keyboard* and use it as any other keyboard layout.

[image]

Comment: Really strange, i tried everything, but it does not work.
Reboot etc.
Is there anything else needed, it just does not show up in the menu. 
I added it correctly to the xml.

Comment: @Gabriel: There is nothing else AFAIK. I actually did it successfully on my machine. Where in the menu did you look? You should choose "English (United States)", and then it should be included in the sub menu.

Comment: strange, it seems I had some issues with spaces not sure, however the thing was buggy, eventually it workes like you explained