# Changing character input of one key on keyboard (not entire keyboard layout)

Tags: server, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language

I have a handful of Ubuntu Servers (all of them the latest version) and as you know the / symbol is used very frequently. I've gotten used to my native language keyboard layout (Icelandic) but the / symbol there is Shift+7 which is inconvient when typing it so often. I would like to use the US keyboard location for this symbol (in the icelandic keyboard layout that is the þ character which I never use while managing the servers).

I have tried searching for a solution but the required search terms elude me, I only find unrelated solutions or solutions requiring a complete layout change.

In short, I would like to keep the default icelandic keyboard layout but change the input of only one key, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's such a small change, simply opening the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/is` file and editing it directly is probably the easiest way.

An alternative is to create an Icelandic layout variant which you could name `programming` for instance. The other day I wrote an example of that kind of change in [an answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1460248).