# Switch two Keys "Backtick" with "<" in keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

This is a follow up of [Where should `setxkbmap us_programmer` go to make it persistent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460123/where-should-setxkbmap-us-programmer-go-to-make-it-persistent/1460248?noredirect=1#comment2555229_1460248)

which worked: So I wanted to simple remap the two keys, but was not sure if the `<KPAD>` is the right abbrev? How do I get this abbrev?

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "programmer" {

    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1] = "English (US, switch stuff)";

    key <TLDE> {     [  greater      ,less]  };
    key <KPAD> {     [  grave        ,asciitilde  ]  };
};
```

[image]

Comment: See https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00052000000000000000

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can see which keyboard keycode table is actively used?

in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/???`

Comment: I think ti's named <LSGT>.

Comment: Thanks that was it.

I used `showkey --keycodes` which returns differet keycodes to `xev --event keyboard` which should be used.